# Received an email from Apple that states that I use the same swift libraries

Tags: swift, libraries

Today I received this email, can someone help me to fix the problem that apple is having here?

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for >"myDiveApp". To process your delivery, the following issues must be >corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The watchOS application has Swift libraries at >both /Payload/myDiveApp.app/myDiveApp watchApp.app/myDiveApp watchApp ?>Extension.appex/Frameworks/ and /Payload/myDiveApp.app/myDiveApp >watchApp.app/Frameworks/. Remove all of the Swift libraries from one of >the locations and resubmit your app.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the >corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick was to disable 'Embedded Content Contains Swift Code'

[image: Xcode Setting]

Comment: Nowadays (Xcode 9) it was "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" that I had to delete (or set to No), but yes, basically this.